# Armar arbol con dos diferentes tablas en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito que cuando yo haga una consulta a la base de datos por ejemplo esta:

```
SELECT *
FROM cpt_parteprod pp
inner join cpp_parteprod2 pp2 on pp.nro_trans=pp2.nro_trans
where pp.nro_lote='CBUS2312061046';
```

Si la columna 'seccion' contiene la letra 'C' necesito hacer una consulta hija para esa fila, y que me figure como que esa consulta depende de la fila, como si desplegara un arbol.

Esto no se si es posible. Pero me gustaria saber si se puede lograr

Comment: ¿Cuál es la idea de lo que estás proponiendo?

Comment: justo lo que comenta @padaleiana , puedes enseñarnos qué estás esperando obtener? como adicional, es recomendable enseñar las estructuras de las tablas con las que estás trabajando, por lo menos los campos relevantes, un select * from table no nos dice mucho

Comment: SQL devuelve tablas.. no arboles.. que lo puedas simular, con miles de datos repetidos, no quiere decir que sea optimo...

Comment: ¿Quizás hablamos del tipo de datos **hierarchyid** y estructuras de datos [jerárquicos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server) ?